# Valuable Inventory: No content

Tags: google-adsense

i m running blog-spot.com URL since 2010 adsense adds everything was working fine, i buy a new domain from go-daddy.com November 2018 and my ads space become blank i add my site in google adsense "ADD Site" now they said that " Your site isn’t ready to show ads We’ve found some policy violations on your site which means your site isn’t ready to show ads yet. Valuable Inventory: No content,
i put it twice for re-review but answer is same,

my blog don't have plagiarism contact, i haven't seen any policy violation, please help me i don't know how to solve this issue,

webpage is markizin.com

Comment: I have few posts on wallpapers is that the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because technically you have zero content due to the fact that your canonical is set to `HTTP://` not `HTTPS://` e.g `<link href='http://www.markizin.com/' rel='canonical'/>`.

Set the canonical to `HTTPS://` and Google's bots will have an easier time.

Comment: thank you for answer, but i check my URL Canonical Status its on https instead of http . please can you explain where to check canonical status. i check this status on seoreviewtools.com/canonical-url-location-checker/

Comment: The canonical occurred in your HTML source code which I can see you have now updated. The one in the JSON is also correct. If you search Google `markizin.com` you will see that `www.markizin.com` is returned in the results and not HTTPS. You should add all variations to Google Search Console (GSC) and you should put less faith in 3rd party SEO tools since GSC would have told you which variation was indexed.